# Laravel - data not being passed to model::create() from repository

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5

I am stumped by this one. I want to add a json encoded array to the data which is being passed to my model.

In my model I have a mutator which will perform some custom work on the array before submission.

However even though I am certain that the data exists in the $data array, when I Log the value in the model I get nothing back. Any ideas are appreciated.

**MyRepository.php**

```
$data['additionalAttributes'] = json_encode($additionalAttributes);
Log::debug($data);
return MyModel::create($data);
```

**MyModel.php**

```
 //The following returns null for no reason.
 Log::debug($this->additionalAttributes);
```

additionalAttributes has been set in the fillable property also. All of the other attributes are loggable except this one? Any ideas on why this is the case?

***Update***

I have determined this to be a bug caused by the "Attributes" term being part of the property name. I tried changing the name of the property to "AdditionalStuff" and it worked right away. I have reported the issue on github at the following link.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13460

The next example works fine. The only change is the name.

***MyRespoitory.php***

```
$data['additionalStuff'] = json_encode($additionalStuff); 
Log::debug($data); 
return MyModel::create($data);
```

The following returns the expected output.

MyModel.php

```
Log::debug($this->additionalStuff);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be logging `$value` rather than `$this->additionalAttributes`?

Comment: Did you define the $fillable attribute on your model?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: @JoelHinz Thanks for the reply. No that just an example, I have more in my mutator but the log is only testing to see if the current value of the additionalAttributes is even set. I have verified that this is a bug in the framework. I will update the question now with details.

Comment: @Pascal Hi Pascal, yeah I sure did. I have verified this to be a bug. I am updating the question now with details and I have reported it to Laravel on github also.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined this to be a bug see the question above for details and the issue as reported on github.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13460

Answer (score 0):

Its tied to the [accessors & mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). Because of that the 'Attribute' suffix is reserved for field names.

Comment: Yeah this was the first thing that I looked at when I realised what was happening. But I would have thought it would work since its "Attributes" and not "Attribute" and as such the mutator would be named "setAdditionalAttributesAttribute".